# getting error in running mlflow ui on vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, mlflow

I am getting the error after running the command ****mlflow ui ****in vs code

```
AttributeError: 'EntryPoints' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I have tried downgrading this using:

```
pip install "importlib-metadata<5.0"
```